# DateDiff is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(Module.url, Module.username, Module.password);
String sql3 = "Update resume set DateDifference=DATEDIFF(End, Now())";
ps3 = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
ps3.executeUpdate();
```

[image]

Datatype of End is DATE & DateDifference is Varchar.
Its not updating the table in the database.
Can anyone help me pls.

i try to locate the problem using System.out.println("Test1") on each line its only printing up to ps3 = con.prepareStatement(sql3); there is a problem on ps3.executeUpdate();

I think its not updating because of NULL value.

Comment: what date format is `End` in?

Comment: Not related to Netbeans at all .

Comment: @Raptor sorry i will edit the question

Comment: @TomMac ohh its only a Date

Comment: what if the query is executed in MySQL workbench ?

Comment: @Raptor its successfully updated but when i try it to Java Netbeans its not updating

Comment: i try to locate the problem using System.out.println("Test1") on each line
its only printing up to ps3 = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
there is a problem on ps3.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to convert the `datediff()` function to `char(50)`. hope this helps

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(Module.url, Module.username, Module.password);
String sql3 = "Update resume set DateDifference=cast(DATEDIFF(End, Now()) as char(50))";
ps3 = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
ps3.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: i try to locate the problem using System.out.println("Test1") on each line its only printing up to ps3 = con.prepareStatement(sql3); there is a problem on ps3.executeUpdate(); but idont know what is the problem on my codes

Comment: @XyryleBuen you can filter `where end is not null`